# Panel visible=true has no effect

Tags: asp.net, visibility

I have a Panel that I'm setting `visible=true` explicitly. The debugger passes over that line and `visible` still evaluates to `False` on the next line. Obviously as a result, the Panel is not shown. How is this possible?

```
pnlValidate.Visible = true;
if (IsPostBack) return;
```

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pnlValidate" runat="server">
    <asp:Button cssclass="submit2" ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Visible="false" text="Validate" OnClick="btnValidate_Click" /> <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt6sql" runat="server" Visible="false" TextMode="multiLine" Width="500" Height="200" ReadOnly="true" ToolTip="Report SQL Statement" />
</asp:Panel>
```

ASP.NET 2.0, no other threads or wonky errata that "should" be messing with my members.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Is your panel nested inside another panel or any other type of container which has Visible set to false?

For such a situation the behaviour your observed is reproducable. It would make sense to forbid to set visibility to true for the inner container if an outer container is invisible since that means nothing inside must be visible, even not the empty div of the inner panel.

The Visible property seems to be dependent on the visibility of outer containers, for instance:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel0" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
        Content...
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

This code is as expected (make outer container visible first, then inner container):

```
Panel0.Visible = true;
// Now Panel0.Visible returns true and Panel1.Visible returns false
Panel1.Visible = true;
// Now Panel0.Visible returns true and Panel1.Visible returns true
```

This code is somewhat surprising (make inner container visible first, then outer container):

```
Panel1.Visible = true;
// Now Panel1.Visible returns false (!, your issue) and Panel0.Visible returns false
Panel0.Visible = true;
// Now Panel1.Visible returns true (!!) and Panel0.Visible returns true
```

It seems that setting and getting the Visible property is "asymmetric": The Setter seems to place a flag in the control, but the Getter to return a calculated value which depends on the visibility of the outer elements and the visibility of the control itself.

Not sure if this will help you at all.

Comment: Correct answer, but silly behaviour. I have conditions to show various elements in a panel (which also contains static elements), and then show the panel if any of them are visible. This forces me to show the panel with an unreadable boolean expression before the logic for each item.

Comment: It's an old question but I faced same behaviour without any cause - except that the page has two UpdatePanels and even this panel staying between them (outside both of them) the panel did not start. I had to put the PANEL within one of the UpdatePanels... VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

By default panel has no border.  Your panel is there you are just not seeing it because it is empty.  Set borderwidth="1" and you will see your empty panel.

Comment: But pnlValidate.Visible = false

Answer (score 0):

*Problem solved*: Panel became visible when I removed `visible="false"` from child controls.

Comment: Something else must be setting it's visibilty or the debugger is going wonky. Do you see a <div> in your rendered HTML with the client ID of this panel? If so, it's there.

Comment: @nickyt: Remember that setting and getting a property is not assigning a value to a public data field in an object. It is calling methods; there is no guarantee that the method for "get" returns the same value you've set with "set".