# How to check whether asp panel is visible or not in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written below lines of codes

```
  in aspx file
 <asp:Panel runat="server" style="margin-bottom:5px;" ID="DocumentStyle">
 <asp:Panel>

 in aspx.cs
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        bool documentPanel = DocumentStyle.Visible;
 }
```

I have to check whether panel is visible or not. The above code is not working!!!

Comment: it gives an error or `documentPanel` is always false?

Comment: i had a same requirement. I have done it using hidden field.

Comment: not any error!!! its always false or true...

Comment: Do you get a compiler or a runtime error? Why is it 'not working'?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is the panel nested into another invisible panel? Perhaps you should check [hits question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539204/panel-visible-true-has-no-effect) on how Visible works with nested panels

Comment: "Its always false or true" ?!?

Comment: If it is hidden by settings the style (visibility or display) it will not change the value of `DocumentStyle.Visible`

Comment: @user2179026 the last comment makes no sense. How did the visibility of the panel change? Do you have other code that changes the panel's visibility? Is the panel nested inside another whose visibility changed?

Comment: @ user2179026 den is it always false??

Comment: @user2179026 the ASPX shows a *visible* panel. How does it become *in*visible? Do you change its Visible property in some other code or did you change its style?

Comment: yes i change its value by modifying visible property not by css property

Comment: So, can you please tell us exactly what doesn't work?

Comment: bool documentPanel = DocumentStyle.Visible; is always false